# Nintex Workflow and SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, infopath, infopath-2007, nintex-workflow

I have designed an `InfoPath 2007` form and in the form there is a drop down list box  with `5 names` of `ICT Focal Point` persons. I want to design `nintex` workflow that is based on who ever is selected from my list, he/she will get a notification to approve the form NOT everyone in the list. In this case only selected person should get the request for approval message and then should approve or reject the request.

I now have some small idea on designing Approval workflow but i have no idea to accomplish this very task in my form.How can i do this. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is just fill up the combobox with de display names of the users.
This way it's easier for nintex to get the right user.
Also make sure you allow users to edit the data of the combobox field or else the field won't be visible in your nintex designer.

In the approval action you only have to select the right item property. 
In your case this will be the name of your combobox field.

Now publish the workflow to the library where you use the infopath form.
Make sure you use the right workflow settings. (when the workflow has to start)

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to accomplish this is to use a variable in your workflow that represents the person that you want to assign the approval to.  Assuming this workflow is activated when a form is submitted you would initialize this variable using a Build Dynamic String shape.

If the value of drop down is a promoted field you could read it as a list item. If it is not a promoted field you can read the value using XPATH.

You would then use a Request Approval shape setting the approver to the workflow variable.